# Data alignment in structure in x86-64

Tags: c, struct, alignment

Here is a textbook problem from *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective, 3rd Edition* (Global Edition) on page 311, Section 3.9:

> **Practice Problem 3.44** (solution page 381)
>
> For each of the following structure declarations, determine the offset of each field, the total size of the structure, and its alignment requirement for x86-64:
>
> A. `struct P1 { short i; int c; int *j; short *d; };`
>
> ...
>
> D. `struct P4 { char w[16]; char *c[2]; };`
>
> E. `struct P5 { struct P4 a[2]; struct P1 t; };`

I have a couple of question about padding. I have learned that padding is applied by default.

So I think **offset of struct P1** should be

```
i    c    j    d    total    alignment
---------------------------------------
0    2    8    16    24         8
```

and for **struct P5**

```
a    t    total    alignment
----------------------------
0    64     96        8
```

since total size of P4 is 32byte.
But the textbook solution is different. I think I am correct.

Solution suggests

```
i    c    j    d    total    alignment
---------------------------------------
0    2    6    14    16         8


a    t    total    alignment
----------------------------
0    24     40        8
```

Comment: Don't *think*, find out for sure what happens with your particular compiler and os and CPU combination using `offsetof()`. And realize it might be different with a different environment or different compiler flags.

Comment: The answer is implementation defined.  Since you've not identified the implementation you are using, nor the implementation that the authors are using, no-one can help.  You've not identified explicitly whether you're working with 32-bit or 64-bit pointers; that definitely factors into the answer.  It is unlikely that `c` in the `struct P1` is 2; it is probably 4.

Comment: It looks like the book is assuming 32-bit pointers whereas you're assuming 64-bit pointers.  Yes, the answers will be different, therefore.  Both correct, but both dependent on the specific implementation.  (I still think `c` won't be at offset 2 — it certainly isn't on a Mac running macOS 10.14.1 Mojave with GCC 8.2.0 or with Apple's Clang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)).

Comment: Unless you can edit the question and specify which system and compiler you have in mind, it isn't possible to answer - the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The exact details of structure padding are implementation defined.  However, compilers do tend to place fields at an alignment suitable for their type.

Assuming 8 byte pointers (given that you're on an x86-64 machine) 4 byte `int` and 2 byte `short`, you're *mostly* correct.  The `c` field in `P1`, being an `int`, will probably start at a 4 byte offset, but the rest of the fields should be at the same offsets.  The size of `P5` will also only need to be 88 (64 for 2 P4's and 24 for 1 P1) since only 8 byte alignment would be required as opposed to 16 byte alignment.

Given this code:

```
printf("sizeof p1 = %zu\n", sizeof(struct P1));
printf("sizeof p4 = %zu\n", sizeof(struct P4));
printf("sizeof p5 = %zu\n", sizeof(struct P5));
printf("P1 offset: %zu, %zu, %zu, %zu\n",
    offsetof(struct P1, i), offsetof(struct P1, c),
    offsetof(struct P1, j), offsetof(struct P1, d));
printf("P4 offset: %zu, %zu\n",
    offsetof(struct P4, w), offsetof(struct P4, c));
printf("P5 offset: %zu, %zu\n",
    offsetof(struct P5, a), offsetof(struct P5, t));
```

My x86-64 CentOS 7 machine with gcc 4.8.5 outputs:

```
sizeof p1 = 24
sizeof p4 = 32
sizeof p5 = 88
P1 offset: 0, 4, 8, 16
P4 offset: 0, 16
P5 offset: 0, 64
```

The book you're using seems to be using 4 byte pointers and assumes either no alignment or packed structures.

For more details, take a look at [The Lost Art of Structure Padding](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).